# Continue script if search has no results selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I automated the export of some reports, based on registration numbers in list RegistrationNr.

This is the logic:

Step 1) Type the registration number into the search box (without this, the html code will not be found)

Step 2) Click on the registration number

Step 3) Go and export the report of this organization.

With my current code, if there is a number on the list which is not in the database, the program stops because it has no number to click on. How can I make it look for the next item on the list whenever this happens?

This is my code:

```
 for i in RegistrationNr:

      driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@title = "Searchbox"]').send_keys(i)

      driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@title =" + ' "'+ i +'"' + "]").click()

      driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@title = "Number"]').click()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be simply achieved using try and except. Please find the code below

```
for i in RegistrationNr:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@title = "Searchbox"]').send_keys(i)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@title =" + ' "'+ i +'"' + "]").click()

    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@title = "Number"]').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Element is not present in the database")
```

Comment: Thanks! I added a ‘continue’ at the bottom and it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply validate presence of elements with `find_elements` method.
In case elements found it will return a non-empty list which is seen by Python as Boolean `True`. Otherwise it will return an empty list which is seen by Python as a Boolean `False`.
So your code can be something like this:

```py
for i in RegistrationNr:

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@title = "Searchbox"]').send_keys(i)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@title =" + ' "'+ i +'"' + "]").click()
    results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/*[@title = "Number"]')
    if(results):
        results[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `find_elements` inside try-except block. Use the len function to check if  `find_elements` has return at least 1 web element, if it has then click on it else, skip it.

**Code:**

```
for i in RegistrationNr:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@title = "Searchbox"]').send_keys(i)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@title =" + ' "'+ i +'"' + "]").click()
    try:
        if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[@title = 'Number']")) >0:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@title = 'Number']").click()
        else:
            # do something here when .//*[@title = 'Number'] is not available
    except:
        pass
```